# Is there any coffee candy that actually has a similar effect to drinking coffee?

Tags: coffee-culture

A friend gave me a little coffee-flavored candy yesterday. I don't really know where this comes from, but it's just like a jolly-rancher or butter drop, just coffee flavored.

But are there any quality  coffee candies about that have a similar effect to drinking coffee?

Comment: If I'm thinking of the same candy, it's kind of like a coffee version of a Werther's original. It has the same hard consistency and sticks to my teeth just the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are chocolate covered coffee bean candies.

They look something like that:

[image: coffee_drop_candies]

We may build an equation such as: one cup of espresso includes around 7 grams of coffee, 7 grams of coffee could be grounded around 50 mid-sized beans. So, if you eat 50 of these drops, it will be roughly equal to a cup of coffee.

(Plus fibers, potassium and many others that I cannot list now without checking a paper.)

Answer (score 2):

While not quite candy, the [Peanut Toffee Buzz flavor Clif Bar](http://www.clifbar.com/products/clif/clif-bar/peanut-toffee-buzz) contains 45mg of caffeine. Combined with 10g of protein and some sugar I usually get a decent buzz comparable to a shot of espresso.

I've also been seeing chocolate products from [Awake Chocolate](http://www.awakechocolate.com) here in the U.S. I couldn't find exact caffeine amounts on their website, but those over at Caffeine Informer have [done the research](https://www.caffeineinformer.com/caffeine-content/awake-chocolate) for us. They sell bite-sized pieces with around 50 mg of caffeine and full bars with around 100 mg. Of course, like the Clif Bars, you'll also be getting a fair amount of sugar.

Comment: Awake chocolate now lists the caffeine content on their website in mg. And yes, [50 mg is listed in the description for the Awake Bites](https://awakechocolate.com/collections/bites/products/original-bites-variety-pack) under the "add to cart" button. The amount of sugar in the dark chocolate bite is about equal to 2.33 hershey kisses but weighs as much as 3 so the bite is about 0.44̅4 g of sugar per gram whereas the kiss is about 0.556 g of sugar per gram.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are coffee and espresso flavoured candy. This is a specialty candy and a bit esoteric in many countries but you can find at least half a dozen brands at larger grocers, specialty candy stores or online.

Some better quality brands include Britt's (chewy), Bali's (hard) & Lindt (mocha chocolate bar). The OP's request for candy with an experience similar to coffee is ambiguous though.

There is hard candy, taffe type chewy candies, mocha chocolate (so good) and of course chocolate covered espresso beans. Flavours range from mild & very similar to coffee to intense & almost espresso-like.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are, you might want to check out [Scho-Ka-Kola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scho-Ka-Kola), a German chocolate product with ground coffee and kola nut. Developed in 1935, it was (in)famous during WW II and is, virtually unchanged, still available today.